# How to use OpenTripPlanner inside of a javascript website?

Tags: javascript, java, opentripplanner

I am fairly new to the OpenTripPlanner and would like to implement it into a small portion of an already built website. Is this possible and if so how would I go about adding it?

Comment: Why have you tagged Java if the website is JavaScript?  Java != JavaScript.

Comment: OpenTripPlanner is written in Java so I thought I should add the tag.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenTripPlanner platform provides a web front-end to plan journeys so you can embed that into your website using an iframe.

http://docs.opentripplanner.org/en/latest/Basic-Tutorial/#simple-one-step-server

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe